# retrieve all records which it's meta record contain author id has the newest date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. The first one called `subject` and the other called `comment`.
As it clear, subject table has one to many relation to comment.
below is the Schema of those tables:
`subject`:

```
__________________________
| id | subject_id | title |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1          | health|
--------------------------
| 2  | 2          | sport |
---------------------------
| 3  | 5          | food  |
---------------------------
```

comment:

```
----------------------------------------
| id | user_id | subject_id | date      |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 10      | 1          | 2018-07-04|
-----------------------------------------
| 2  | 9       | 1          | 2018-07-03|
-----------------------------------------
| 3  | 10      | 1          | 2018-07-02|
----------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve all subject_id form subject table which have user_id=10 and have max date. I this case the result must be like this:
only one record and it's subject_id =1;

```
$query = "SELECT subject_id FROM subject AS s, comment AS c WHERE 
           s.subject_id = c.subject_id AND c.user_id = 10
           GROUP BY MAX(c.date)
```

but unfortunately, it returns subject_id according to number of comments related to a specific subject:

## first I can select all comment with the max date

`SELECT  * FROM comment  GROUP BY subject_id HAVING max(date)` 
the unanswered question is how I can filter through those record in order to retrieve latest comment with user_id = 10

Comment: `and earlier date` What does it means??

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: do you want one row for each subject_id (if there is comment for every subject) and which should be first comment (based on your statement earlier date)?

Comment: @ShakeerMirza I mean which has newest date

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be grouping aggregates like you did. If this is the entire query you should be sorting on the date and limiting your output to the first row:

```
select s.subject_id
from subject s
inner join comment c on
  s.subject_id = c.subject_id
where c.user_id = 10
order by c.date desc
limit 1
```

Note that I've replaced old-fashioned `,` joining syntax with `JOIN` keyword

Comment: Hello downvoter, what's wrong with this answer? Please be so kind to justify your vote :)

Comment: I select all records which have the max date . how can I filter them by user id?
`select SELECT  * FROM comment  GROUP BY subject_id HAVING max(date)`

Comment: This isn't valid SQL. If you need to filter user_id you need a WHERE condition. Please show us your expected result given your data (edit your question).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use aggregate i think sub-query will help you in below way

```
select subject_id from
(
select subject_id,max(date) from subject
inner join comment on subject.subject_id=comment.subject_id
where comment.user_id=10
group by subject_id
) as T
```

Comment: @hello downvoter can you please say why you put down vote , so that i can correct myself